# Xcode 8.1 Swift 3 convertion very slow

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Yesterday i installed Xcode 8.1 and started converting my Swift 2.2 codes to Swift 3 using Xcode conversion tool. 
Conversion is very slow, its already around 14 hrs, the progress indicator has moved only a little. Still its loading with "Generating preview". 
My project has around 150 files, 7 libraries (imported using Carthage) and 40 screens.

Is this normal?
how long will take normally?.

Comment: That's way too long. Conversion on my machine of a project roughly half the size took ~30 seconds. I would bet you're hitting a bug in the conversion tool that's preventing it from continuing, but also from erroring out.

Comment: It should only take *a few minutes* maximum for a big project. Something's wrong.

Comment: it's not Normal. Restart your system and Xcode and give it a try again.

Comment: @Wolverine First time after hitting 2 hrs and slow progress, i tried restarting System, this is 2nd time. i thought its normal.

Comment: If you have Xcode8 and then give it a try with that.

Comment: @Wolverine I will have a try. In my system i have Xcode 7.3 and Xcode 8.1 installed. Is that the reason? any idea?

Comment: No, Its not wrong. 8.1 should do the work. but as it is not working in your case, give it a try with Xocde8 in which Swift 3 was the first major released.

Comment: @Wolverine Do i have to check Pods.framework while conversion? i am trying with one other project after System restart.

Comment: Which cocoa-pod version you are currently using ? You should update the cocoa-pod version and repo.

Comment: Any progress with this issue? I have this issue too. But not in every projects. last month I convert the first project and it was fine. But now I can't convert it (tried in 2 macs).

Comment: I tried the xcode 8.0, but no luck